# Group By (Aggregation) to get only latest fields value

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, metricbeat

I write a query to read the metricbeat file. This gives me the whatever I want but it repeats the value multiple time.

I want to group by this on latest timestamp so I can get only latest record.

Below is my query

```
string indexName = "metricbeat-7.4.2-" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("00") + "." + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString("00");
connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool).DefaultIndex(indexName);
elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

            string[] systemFields = new string[]
            {
                "system.memory.actual.used.pct",
                "system.cpu.total.norm.pct"                
            };

            var elasticResponse = elasticClient.Search<object>(s => s
                .DocValueFields(dvf => dvf.Fields(systemFields))
                );
```

DSL query

```
get /metricbeat*/_search?pretty=true
 { 
   "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "docvalue_fields" : [
      "system.memory.actual.used.pct",
      "system.cpu.total.norm.pct",
      "system.load.5",
      "docker.diskio.summary.bytes"
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Please add the raw query (json).

Comment: Added, check last part of my post.